# How do I build _tkinter.py

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting an error that the _tkinter.py is not found and I do not see this python module on my system. I am on Ubuntu, after some reading it seems I need to download and build that compiled module for Python.

Where do I get the code to build that module? and where is it installed in Ubuntu? I asssume this will be a configure / autoconfig type of build.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: If you build Python from source, `tkinter` source code is already included but you need to have the development packages of tcl/tk installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed tkinter?

If not, typing this in cmd should work
`sudo apt install python3-tk`

Comment: Thanks I had already tried that, but thanks for the comment.